# crypto library for Xen hypervisor

Tags: cryptography, kernel, xen, hypervisor

Im trying to implement a hypercall in Xen kernel that would perform cryptographic operation inside Xen hypervisor.

Xen source code doesn't contain libraries for Crypto, how should I go about implementing my hypercall? In particular, what are the "kernel-based" crypto libraries I can use to compile into Xen and use for my hypercall?

Answer (score 0):

In XEN, most of the drivers are implemented using the domain 0.

You can use it to implement your cryptographic operations in a virtio driver and have all Linux cryptographic kernel libraries at hand.